# Pass id to form using ajax in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

I try to pass id to form in modal, but i got error *The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.* Although I use it.
this is a web route:
`Route::post('bill/{id}', 'MemberController@addBill')->name('bill');`
this is the view :
`<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#message" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-id="{{ $r->id }}" ></button>`

this is a modal

```
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">اثبات الدفع</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>من فضلك قم بادخال صوره التحويل البنكى</p>
            <form action="" method="post" id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
              <div class="form-group">
                 <input type="file" name="select_file" id="select_file">
             </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" name="upload" id="upload" class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload">jj</button>
        </div>
          </form>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

this is a ajax request :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $('#upload').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
   var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var id = button.data('id');
    var formData = new FormData($('upload_form')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url : '/member/bill/'.id,
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,            
        success: function(d){
            console.log(d.message);
        }
    });

</script>
```

please help me!

Comment: have you tried  url : '/bill/'.id insted of  url : '/member/bill/'.id, in your ajax

Comment: no it is with group name member

Answer (score 0):

**01. check your MemberController, addBill() method**

```
public function addBill(Request $request) {

 // your code here...

}
```

Comment: thx, i solved this error by put hidden input to carry id, and i don't need id with route.